# How to handle Jupyter Notebook NBextension config error?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I installed nbextension to my Jupyter Notebook. But when I was using large datasets it made a big slow down. Then I removed NBExtension but after uninstallation, 500 Internal Server error started. Now I tried to reinstall Anaconda but the problem is still there.

```
     nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main enabled
  - Validating: problems found:
    - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main
  contrib_nbextensions_help_item/main enabled
  - Validating: ok
  hinterland/hinterland enabled
  - Validating: ok
  autosavetime/main enabled
  - Validating: ok
  select_keymap/main enabled
  - Validating: ok
  jupyter-js-widgets/extension disabled
tree section
  nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main enabled
  - Validating: problems found:
    - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main
edit section
  ruler/edit enabled
  - Validating: ok
  codefolding/edit enabled
  - Validating: ok
config dir: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\etc\jupyter\nbconfig
notebook section
  jupyter-js-widgets/extension enabled
  - Validating: ok
  nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main enabled
  - Validating: problems found:
    - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main
tree section
  nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main enabled
  - Validating: problems found:
    - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main
config dir: C:\ProgramData\jupyter\nbconfig
notebook section
  nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main enabled
  - Validating: problems found:
    - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main
tree section
  nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main enabled
  - Validating: problems found:
    - require?  X nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

`jupyter nbextensions_configurator disable`

or

`conda remove jupyter_nbextensions_configurator` ?

Comment: WHen I click on my notebook Menu I get error: ``` [IPKernelApp] ERROR | No such comm target registered: jupyter.widget.control
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 39e3dd55-5816-44a7-b2fa-f19e4b645f36
```